# git submodule update --no-checkout?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a git repo that contains a fairly large submodule I need to add a few items to. I'd rather not clone and checkout the whole working tree.

With a clone, I could do `git clone <repo> --no-checkout`, but that doesn't seem to be an option for this submodule. That's my current solution:

```
git clone <remote-path-to-MySubmodule> --no-checkout
cd MySubmodule
cp path/to/files/* .
git add path/to/files/*
git commit -m <message>
git push
```

but it feels like the `submodule` workflow should allow this too.

Comment: a possible (but seemingly *awful*) solution is to `git submodule init MySubmodule`, then `echo gitdir: ../.git/modules/MySubmodule>MySubmodule/.git`

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're doing here. You have an existing submodule: a submodule is a clone, so you have two clones, one being the superproject, one being the submodule. What is it that you want to do in the existing submodule-clone?

Comment: @torek a submodule isn't *strictly* a clone though, since the index is contained in the topmost parent in a tree of submodules. My workaround is to `git clone --no-checkout` so I can keep from building the working tree, but I'd rather stay within the submodule workflow

Comment: Well, the index file is moved (in modern "absorbed" submodules), yes. Logically, the index "belongs with" the work-tree; `git worktree add` has to play games with the added work-tree index files (and the `HEAD` file that goes with them). It sounds like you're wishing for a `git submodule worktree add`, more or less. Of course that doesn't exist, alas.

Comment: In any case, to make a new commit, you just need to add files to the/an index, because each new commit is made by freezing the index. You can always copy the existing index, as long as you've also copied the work-tree, and then use `GIT_INDEX_FILE=<path> git --git-dir=<path> --work-tree=<path> ...` to do commands there. It's not exactly *clean*... (and remember that the HEAD file, or its target if it is a symbolic ref, gets modified in the process). It's probably safer to just make a local clone, which of course is what you don't want, or just work directly in the submodule work-tree.

Answer (score 1):

> I'd rather not clone and checkout the whole working tree

If you wish to clone the repository but you dont need the full history do a **shallow clone**

```
# --branch=<branch> Clone only specific branch 
# --depth=1 clone only the last 1 commits 

git clone <url> --branch=<branch_name> --depth=<X>   
git clone <url> --branch=master --depth=1
```

---

As requested in the comment below

## How to create orphan branch?

#### What is orphan branch?

Orphan branch is branch without any history. Using the `git checkout -b <name>` will create branch with the current branch full history.

Using orphan branch is creating an "orphan" branch with no history.

```
git checkout --orphan branch_name
```

Comment: I don't need any history, really. I just need an empty working tree and an initialized index. I'm not sure `git clone` (of any variety) is my preferred solution

Comment: Can u use orpah branch? orphan branch is branch without any history

Comment: I don't think so. My new commit should push back to remote one commit after the supermodule's pointer on its branch (let's call it `master`)

Comment: So use the `--depth` as explained above, this will only checkout teh current commit which are the current files. What do i miss in your Q?

Comment: I think we've gotten off-track there. I don't need the current files. I'm pushing *new* files (not editing existing ones)

Comment: You cant push unless you commit and in order to commit you must have history. It can be current or new (orphan)

Comment: `git submodule init` gives me history in the index. I don't need to have the files in my working tree to have the history that they existed. Presume there are 100,000+ files in this submodule and I'm pushing two more; it's silly to produce the working tree in order to add two more files.

Comment: `git submodule update --init --recursive --depth 1` as before simply add the `depth`

Comment: CodeWizard sorry, but that checks out the working tree. I don't think this is a productive line of inquiry.